# stop rails from erasing HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, formatted-text

I used the TinyMce header link to get formatting options in text input areas
of my RoR 2.3.5 app.

This works fine for sending emails, but when I try to save text in the database, the HTML tags get erased and it is displayed as plain text.

For example,

```
<%= text_area (:inspection, :kashruth_comments, :class => 'tinymce') %>
```

How can I save the tags as well?

Based on [this page](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize) I tried adding into `config\initializers\new_rails_defaults.rb`:

```
 ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_tags.replace %w(strong em b i hr br ul ol li blockquote)
ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_attributes.replace %w(href a)
```

but it did not help.

Comment: Do not put a space between the method name and parens in Ruby! Since parens are optional you're actually calling it with `text_area((:inspection, :kashruth_comments, :class => 'tinymce'))`. which will cause syntax errors as its treated as a single argument instead of a list.

Comment: You're also using docs for Rails 4 which can't be expected to work in such an ancient version of Rails. I don't know if Rails 2 even had automatic HTML sanitation - I believe the feature was added in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the `/vendor/plugins` folder, there is a plugin called `xss-terminate`. In the `README.rdoc` file, I found

> To exempt some fields from sanitization, use the :except
> option  with a list of fields not to process:
>
> class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base    xss_terminate :except => [
> :body ]  end
>
> To sanitize HTML with Rails's built-in sanitization, use the
> :sanitize option:
>
> class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
> xss_terminate :sanitize => [ :body, :author_name]   end

In `models/inspection.rb`, I added

```
  xss_terminate :except => [ :kashruth_comments ]
  xss_terminate :sanitize => [:kashruth_comments]
```

Now, when I entered 'going nuts' as bold and italic, it saves as such.

When I entered `<script>going nuts</script>`, it displays exactly as that, but in the database, it is stored as

```
| <strong>&lt;script&gt;going </strong><em><strong>nuts&lt;/script&gt;</strong></em> |
```

Does that look correct?